# fire an onChange event while setting the initial value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a select field which will "select" an Entry automatically when there is only one entry in the list. My Problem is, that there will no onChange event triggered, when setting the value in the list. Is there any possibility to send these event programatically?

This is my code so far

```
export const SelectField = function(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const {t} = useTranslation();

    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(undefined);

    if (selectedValue === undefined && props.menuEntries.length === 1) {
        setSelectedValue(props.menuEntries[0]);
        //need to fire an event in this case
    } else if (props.addSelectEntry) {
        props.menuEntries.push({"name":t("select"), "value":""});
    }

    return  (
        <Select
            value={selectedValue}
            onChange={props.onChange()}
            name={props.name}
            displayEmpty
            className={classes.selectEmpty}
        >
            {props.menuEntries.map(entry => (
                <MenuItem key={entry.name} value={entry.value}>
                    {entry.name}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}

        </Select>);
};
```

Comment: ` onChange={props.onChange}` - Should be like this

Comment: @UKS Thanks for your suggestion. But the onChange function is not called. It looks like that this handler is only called in the onClose Method of the drop down

Comment: `onChange` will trigger when we change the menuItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by calling he handler by my own, if i set the initial value:

```
export const SelectField = function(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(props.value);

    // on startup load test cases
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedValue === props.value && props.menuEntries.length === 1) {
            setSelectedValue(props.menuEntries[0].value);
            props.onChange(props.menuEntries[0].value);
        }
    }, [selectedValue]);


    const updateValue = function(e) {
        props.onChange(e.target.value);
        setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <Select
            value={selectedValue}
            onChange={updateValue}
            name={props.name}
            displayEmpty
            className={classes.selectEmpty}
        >
        {
            (props.menuEntries.length !== 1 && props.addSelectEntry) && (
                <MenuItem key={t("select")} value={t("select")}>
                    {t("select")}
                </MenuItem>
            )
        }
            {props.menuEntries.map(entry => (
                <MenuItem key={entry.name} value={entry.value}>
                    {entry.name}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}

        </Select>);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference in passing a function as a prop and calling a function.

```
onChange={props.onChange()}
```

Will call that function every render.

```
onChange={props.onChange}
```

Will pass that function to be called by the component.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the onChange function is not called

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your code it seems to be alright, there is however one thing that might cause your problem.

```
return  (
        <Select
            value={selectedValue}
            onChange={props.onChange} <---
            name={props.name}
            displayEmpty
            className={classes.selectEmpty}
        >
            {props.menuEntries.map(entry => (
                <MenuItem key={entry.name} value={entry.value}>
                    {entry.name}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}

        </Select>);
```

I changed how you set the onchange function. You did it while also calling the actual function. This will make the function fire when the component renders and not on the change of your controlled value for this select.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the onChange function is not called

Comment: Ok, if you could show some more code then it would be easier to debug. What does Select component return?

Comment: Your select needs to have selectedValue as a value. 

You could loop out the options with your menuEntries array and return it like above: ```menuEntries.map(menuEntry => (<option value={menuEntry}>{menuEntry}</option>))```

Answer (score 1):

For one is the mentioned `onChange()` to `onChange`, but that is not all.

It seems the issue is connected to code outside of the provided component. One indicator of an issue is the following:

```
....
} else if (props.addSelectEntry) {
    props.menuEntries.push({"name":t("select"), "value":""}); // This line could be faulty
}
....
```

I don't know what kind of value `menuEntries` is, but it should be a state somewhere higher in your component tree. You should also pass in the setter. Probably called something like `setMenuEntries`. Then call that setter in instead of mutate the prop.

```
setMenuEntries([...menuEntries, {"name":t("select"), "value":""}])
```

Only when setting a state a rerender is triggered.

In general, updating props of any function is considered a bad-practise when following the principle of immutability. Eslint can help you with signifying patterns like that.